# I have a strange gap on the right side of my page

Tags: html, css

I made my page according to my assignment, except something I did has caused an additional `15px` to appear on the right of my page, though you have to horizontally scroll to see it. I'm not certain what I did that caused this, but I would really like some help figuring it out and how to fix it.

My code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("images/background.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgb(153, 145, 122);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, aqua, mediumslateblue);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, aqua, mediumslateblue);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, aqua, mediumslateblue);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, aqua, mediumslateblue);
  font: 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
}

header {
  position: inline;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
}

ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 5px
}

.imagesEnlarged {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 45%;
  height: 45%;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 5px
}

.banner {
  background: url("images/background.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.buttonHolder {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.buttonHolderGallery {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 30%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#text {
  Width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: black;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.gallery {}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: left;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: black;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1200px) {
  body {
    font-size: 0.8em;
  }
  .buttonHolder {
    top: 65%;
  }
  footer {
    font-size: 0.9em;
  }
  .client {
    display: inline;
    width: 40%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:800px) {
  body {
    font-size: 0.6em;
  }
  .buttonHolder {
    top: 65%;
  }
  footer {
    font-size: 0.9em;
  }
  .images {
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
  }
}

.fa-facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}

.fa-twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}

.fa-linkedin {
  background: #007bb5;
  color: white;
}

.white {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  float: right
}

.fa {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text- decoration: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.newspaper {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 60px;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-gap: 60px;
  /* Firefox */
  column-gap: 60px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.split {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 80px;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-gap: 80px;
  /* Firefox */
  column-gap: 80px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<header>
  <div class="logo">Photography Masters</div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#link"> About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#link"> Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#link"> Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#link"> Services</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<section class="banner">
</section>

<div id="wrapper">
  <section id="text">
    <h1>About Us</h1>
    <section class="split">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus elementum feugiat risus, a vulputate enim imperdiet at. Suspendisse nec nisi ut sem efficitur pulvinar. Proin eros ex, scelerisque eget eleifend non, vestibulum sit amet lacus. Sed
        dignissim eget libero quis condimentum. Cras ullamcorper aliquet orci ut maximus. Sed congue sem non dui sagittis ultricies non a turpis. Maecenas at mi vestibulum, tempor leo venenatis, sodales massa. Mauris commodo ac mauris a tincidunt. Nunc
        et neque sagittis, ultrices tellus nec, tincidunt mi. Nulla pretium leo libero, quis molestie arcu venenatis et. Phasellus dapibus sem ac tristique gravida. Aliquam felis augue, efficitur egestas orci vitae, convallis viverra nisi. Vivamus quis
        molestie erat, quis gravida arcu. Aliquam enim orci, accumsan sed justo ut, hendrerit lobortis nibh.
        <img class="imagesEnlarged" src=images/about.JPG alt="Model Shoot">
      </p>
    </section>
    <p>Aliquam quis laoreet enim. Nam eu nunc eu sem suscipit ullamcorper bibendum et velit. Nunc sit amet dui elit. Nullam malesuada, leo ut facilisis tristique, neque massa tempor nibh, vel dignissim nulla sapien fringilla orci. Integer sit amet eros vehicula,
      eleifend velit vel, venenatis metus. Quisque mattis semper vulputate. Ut eu malesuada est, non luctus ipsum. Etiam sed urna viverra, tincidunt est vitae, malesuada diam. Pellentesque ipsum nisi, posuere sed sem at, ultrices tempus dolor. Cras suscipit
      non odio sed tincidunt. Nam ut nisi quis elit semper tempus. Proin ac aliquam quam. Sed luctus convallis hendrerit. </p>
    <div class="buttonHolderGallery">
      <input class=button type="submit" value="See More">
    </div>
  </section>
</div>

<footer class="grey2">
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
  <a class="white"> Copyright Photography Masters 2017</a>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The margin on your wrapper `<div>` is causing this. You can change your CSS for this div to something like:

```
margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
```

to remove the margins on the left and the right, just keeping it on the top and bottom; getting rid of the excess space causing your problem.

Answer (score 3):

The right space causing because of this id you added. Just remove width:100%; from this id.

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 5px;
    width: 100%; (no need take this out)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have similar issues I like to debug it by adding a red border to every element to see who is causing the issue

```
*{
  border: 1px solid red!important;
}
```

I was able to reduce the horizontal scroll by removing the margin right of the #wrapper element.

Answer (score 0):

update your **#wrapper** css with.

```
#wrapper {
 padding: 0 2%;
 width: 96%;
}
```